# Is there an option in ReSharper to not remove the blank line I put between the namespace and class definition?

Tags: c#, resharper

Every time I let ReSharper format my code, it removes the blank line I put between the namespace and class declaration.

From this:

```
namespace Test {

  public class Test {
```

To this:

```
namespace Test {
  public class Test {
```

It does the same thing with the blank lines at the closing braces of both.
All my "blank line" settings are set to 1, except for single line fields.

Is there an option I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fsck, just 10 minutes ahead of me. Well, I'll answer anyway. Bad news is that it's a long-time feature request http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-74903

Good news is that it would fixed in the tomorrow's 7.1 EAP build. There would be new options in `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Formatting style | Blank Lines`:

1. `Remove blank lines after "{" and before "}" in declarations` (turn it off to prevent ReSharper from removing blank line) and
2. `Around namespace` and `Around type` (set it to non-zero value to force ReSharper to add blank lines).

Answer (score 20):

This is actually now an option (as of June 2016). Go to `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Formatting style | Other` and check `Line feed at end of file`.

Comment: This is now in the `Line Breaks and Wrapping` node instead of the `Other` node, or just search for "Line feed" as Skorunka suggests.

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio menu: `ReSharper > Options...`

Type in the search box "Line feed at end of file":

[image: Resharper 2018.1.2]